# Calling a JS from VB code on pageload

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net project in which database is being called through VB code.Upon successful request, the div must be animatee left via JQuery.

eg.

**VB code:**

```
    If Confirmationcode = Passcode.text Then
        'Perform the animation here   ...   NextPage();
        'Registerstartupscript doesnt work as this is not in the page_load event
         Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", False)
    End If
```

**js:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function NextPage() {
        $('.Wrapper').animate({ left: '-150%' }, 800);
    };
    </script>
```

It is as simple as:

The animation must be performed, and once completed, then the new aspx page must then load.

Comment: I think you need to learn the difference between client-side code and server-side code - and how the ASP.NET page life-cycle works

Comment: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "click", "NextPage();", True)`.. This works in C# and might work here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you should not use `Response.Redirect` for this situation as you want to first execute the jQuery and then only the page should redirect.

Try something like this:

**VB code:**

```
If Confirmationcode = Passcode.text Then
    'Perform the animation here   ...   NextPage();//don't do this
     int flagAnimate = true;//set one flag here instead which will tell us whether to  animate the div or not
    'Registerstartupscript doesnt work as this is not in the page_load event//not needed
     //Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", False) //no need to redirect from here
End If
```

**js:**

```
<% if(flagAnimate == true){ %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //perform your animation here
    function NextPage() {
      $('.Wrapper').animate({ left: '-150%' }, 800);
    };  
    NextPage();//by calling this function
   //and then redirect the page by using the following code
   self.location.href='/Default.aspx'
  </script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: You are a legend! Thank you, that solves all my queries and things I didn't quite understand in ASP, feels great to have the blanks filled in! :) Thanks!!

Comment: One question, The animation doesn't work as the page refreshes from the button click. Is there anyway to get the animation to actually perform before the page is redirected?

Comment: yeah.. use `setTimeout(function(){   self.location.href='/Default.aspx';},900);` instead of `   self.location.href='/Default.aspx'` Now the page will refresh only after 900 milliseconds.

Comment: Unfortunately the button1_click is refreshing my page because of the post back, so the animation never performs as the page is refreshed and redirected while the animation is "trying" to run. Literally just redirects even with the delay of 900 in.

Comment: Then try to increase the delay... try putting 9000 instead of 900.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. The div stays in the same place for the 9 seconds, and redirects. I however place a new button with the OnClientClick="NextPage(); return false;". During the pause I click the button and the animation occurs. So there is a problem with the animate being called and the postback to the server refreshing the page. Is there anyway to possibly call that specific event of the asp:button?  The "OnClientClick" event only from js?

Comment: I think that should not be the problem, you should check that your script runs after your `wrapper` div is loaded on the page.. change animate function related code to this `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.Wrapper').animate({ left: '-150%' }, 800);});`