# Perfom asp button click, process the VB code and perform Jscript without page refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I would like to click my asp:button (Login button). I would like the button1_click VB code to be performed, after which I have a jscript which determines if the boolean in the button1_click is TRUE and upon true, must perform the jquery animate then redirect the page on the completion of the animation.

The problem I am having is that the page refreshes on the button_click and does not perform the animation before redirecting (The redirecting and everything else works perfectly).

HTML:

```
    <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click">
```

VB Code: (Basic eg of what I am doing)

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       'SQL read to compare username & password etc
       If Passcode = HASHPass Then
            PassCheck = True
       End If
    End Sub
```

JS mixed with VB on .aspx page:

```
    <% If PassCheck = True Then%>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.Wrapper').animate({ left: '-150%' }, 800);

                self.location.href = '/Default.aspx'

            </script>
    <%
        End If%>
```

Is this at all possible to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this and it might do the trick. Here's the code-behind page:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If PassCheck = True Then 'Login completed, do login stuff
        If Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("LoginAnimate") Then
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "LoginAnimate", "$(document).ready( setTimeout('animateLogin()', 500) );", True)
        End If
    Else
        'Do something else if the login failed
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's the header from the ASPX markup:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function animateLogin() {
            $('.Wrapper').animate({ left: '-150%' }, 800, 'swing', startRedirect('/Default.aspx') );
        };

        function startRedirect(pageUrl) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                self.location.href = pageUrl; }, 500); //redirect to pageUrl after 500ms
        };
    </script>
</head>
```

Notice in this instance, we do the server functions in code-behind, and the client functions are placed in the markup, since those functions will not change during page execution. It is my opinion that this makes the code easier to maintain. You could even go so far as to place those functions in a separate .js file, which will allow the browser to cache them separately from the page, reducing bandwidth consumption during page load and postback.

In the Button Click Event Handler, which occurs during postback when the user clicks the button, we do the following:

1. Ensure that PassCheck is True.
2. `If Not IsClientScriptBlockRegistered()` ensures that we haven't already told the server to put this javascript on the page, and then [the server puts the javascript on the page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef(v=vs.110).aspx).

Next, this happens:

1. The page is displayed to the user with the javascript injected as part of the body of the document.
2. Because `$(document).ready( setTimeout('animateLogin()', 500) );` is outside of a function call, the browser will execute the statement as soon as it can. The statement tells the browser to wait for the page to finish loading, then call `animateLogin()` 500 milliseconds after it has finished loading. **This is probably where the animation was failing before:** The page had not fully loaded, but the javascript began executing. Most likely, the element you were trying to animate didn't quite have time to load in the browser before the javascript ran, and it only runs once. Regardless, this new way works for me in tests every time.
3. 500 milliseconds after the page finishes loading, `animateLogin()` does its thing. Once it has finished animating, it calls `startRedirect()`.
4. 1000 milliseconds after calling `startRedirect()`, `location.href` is set, and the browser is redirected.

You can change the delay in milliseconds for the functions by changing the value passed to setTimeout, and you can change the animation time to suit your needs and preferences.

Giving credit where it's due: [time delayed redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877263/time-delayed-redirect)

Comment: I would the structure of everything to fly in from the left. So would like once you have entered the correct username and password, for the div to slide to the left then to let the page redirect. upon Default opening, the new div slides from the right on that page.  The background is all one color so you don't actually see any transition between the 2, well that is the idea. Here is the other post I put up 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713091/calling-a-js-from-vb-code-on-pageload  There I asked how I could call the Jquery from VB, as my original idea was to do the redirect in VB

Comment: @Killua I updated the answer. Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Getting closer, there is now a pause before the page is redirected, however, the animation does not occur. I think it is due to the postback page being refreshed. I now added a seperate asp:button with OnClientClick="NextPage(); return false;" and the nexpage performs the animation. So i click the login button, then during the pause I click the asp button and then the animation works perfectly. But just the LoginButton click doesnt work. Is there maybe a way to call the "OnClientClick" property of the asp button(Now hidden) to perform the animation?

Comment: I'm thinking you'll need to somehow incorporate RegisterStartupScript() into this solution. I see in your other question, it is noted that there is a problem using this method because it is not during Page_Load. Have you tried [this method already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905716/clientscript-registerclientscriptblock)?

Comment: I am not actually sure how I would use the startup script and where to have it registered, and also if the if IsPostBack in the page_load would be used.  I am still very new to ASP so not quite certain how all that works. Is there maybe any way to call the asp:button "OnClientClick" event from jscript? because it works exactly as I want it to, but only when I press that button during the delay.

Comment: @Killua I have updated the solution. I believe this will do exactly what you want. Let me know if you still have questions, and I will be able to respond in a few hours.

Comment: Thanks, that has now officially done the trick!! :) It works like a dream, thanks a lot for your patience and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Change your button into html button and add a web method which performs sql data fetching and returning passcheck = true. Call the webmethod using PageMethods from javascript. It will prevent the page to be refreshed.

Comment: I am actually using Telerik button as I have everything themed accordingly, anyway I could do what you mentioned above using that?